# Date Query MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, date, express

I want to make a query that will select all row from a table...

The Query is : SELECT date from dbuser;

```
+------------+
| date       |
+------------+
| 2015-05-28 |
| 2015-05-29 |
| 1994-11-11 |
| 2010-01-01 |
| 2003-04-30 |
+------------+
```

But the output it's not the same:

```
{ date: Thu May 28 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Romance Summer Time) }
{ date: Fri May 29 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Romance Summer Time) }
{ date: Fri Nov 11 1994 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time) }
{ date: Fri Jan 01 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time) }
{ date: Wed Apr 30 2003 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Romance Summer Time) }
```

I want the output like the table only YYYY-dd-mm:

```
2015-05-28 
2015-05-29
1994-11-11
2010-01-01
2003-04-30
```

my code:

```
 app.get('/admin', function(req, res){
  connection.query("select date from dbsuer", function(err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(results);
    res.send(results);
  });
});
```

Im using nodejs as server side !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  app.get('/admin', function(req, res){
  connection.query("select DATE_FORMAT(date,'%y/%m/%d') AS date from dbsuer", function(err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(results);
    res.send(results);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of allowing your code to format the date, you can force MySQL to convert it to a string for you, using the [`date_format`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y-%m-%d') FROM dbsuer
```

Comment: i try with this one and the output is :
`[ { 'DATE_FORMAT(`date`, \'%Y-%m-%d\')': '2015-05-28' },
  { 'DATE_FORMAT(`date`, \'%Y-%m-%d\')': '2015-05-29' },
  { 'DATE_FORMAT(`date`, \'%Y-%m-%d\')': '1994-11-11' }]`